# Pass php variable to another php page

Tags: php, forms

Is it possible to pass my unique `$comment->comment_id;` to another php file? I want to have the same id for the `li` for that input button. when is clicked I want to pass the variable to the php `"/model/editComment.php"`.

```
<div class="comment-buttons-holder">
    <ul class="comment-buttons-holder-ul">
        <li id="<?php $comment->comment_id; ?>" class="edit-btn">
            <form action ="/model/editComment.php" method="POST">
            <input>" type="submit" value="edit">
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul
```

> Blockquote

```
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Using POST

You've got a form. Use a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="<?php echo $comment->comment_id; ?>" />
```

On your editCommit.php page, you would;

```
$intCommentId = (isset($_POST['comment_id']) AND ctype_digit( (string) $_POST['comment_id'] )) ? (int) $_POST['comment_id'] : 0;
```

#### Using GET

Append it to the action url in the query string.

```
<form action="/model/editComment.php?id=<?php echo $comment->comment_id; ?>"
```

On your editCommit.php page, you would;

```
$intCommentId = (isset($_GET['id']) AND ctype_digit( (string) $_GET['id'] )) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
```

Comment: great! how do get the value in /model/editComment.php?

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help. The way StackOverflow works is, once you've received an answer that has helped and solved your problem, [mark it as accepted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) so it will help others in the future, should they have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<form action ="/model/editComment.php" method="POST">
<input>" type="submit" value="edit">
```

to

```
<form action ="/model/editComment.php?cid=<?php echo $comment->comment_id; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="edit">
```

Comment: `echo $comment->comment_id;`?

Comment: any reason for down voting ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<input type="hidden" name="commentId" value="<?php echo $comment->comment_id; ?>">
```

inside your form to pass a value without showing it to the user.

P.S.:

```
<input>" type="submit" value="edit">
```

seems to be false, try:

```
<input type="submit" value="edit">
```

And i suggest you to add a name to an input, if it has a value.